# Python equivalent of Ruby's .select

Tags: python, ruby

I have an list/array, lets call it `x`, and I want to create a new list/array, lets call this one `z`, out of elements from `x` that match a certain condition.

In Ruby you could do that by calling the .select method on the list/array like so:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
z = x.select{|a| a < 5}
```

After this `z` would look like this:

```
z = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is there a function/method in Python that I could use to get the same effect?

If not, what is the cleanest way I could do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python has a built-in [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
filtered = filter(lambda x: x < 5, lst)
```

But list comprehensions might flow better, especially when combining with map operations:

```
mapped_and_filtered = [x*2 for x in lst if x < 5]
# compare to:
mapped_and_filtered = map(lambda y: y*2, filter(lambda x: x < 5, lst))
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use list comprehension:

```
>>> [a for a in x if a < 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension is considered "Pythonic":

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
z = [i for i in x if i < 5]
print z
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```